# Отображение картинки (waiting box) пока заполняется таблица

Tags: javascript, vue.js

подскажите как сделать, чтобы пока выполняется заполнение таблицы, картинка была видна, а как только таблица заполнится, сразу же исчезала?

Answer (score 1):

Предварительно надо создать компонент, который и есть эта картинка. Ну или просто замутить дивчик, который будет отображаться. Как-то так:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div v-if="preloaderVisibility" class="preloader">Тут контент прелоадера</div>
  <div class="content">Тут остальной контент</div>
</div>
```

В хуке `created()` я бы сделал что-то вроде такого.

```
async created(){
  this.preloaderVisibility = true;
  await axios.get('/targetUrl');
  this.preloaderVisibility = false;
},
data() {
  return {
    preloaderVisibility: false
  }
}
```

То есть, изначально прелоадер фолс. Когда компонент создаётся, мы ставим его в тру. Ждём когда отработает аксиос (или любой другой аякс), когда аксиос вернул инфу, ставим this.preloaderVisibility = false, прелоадер исчезает. Вроде такого.